# How to pass paramaters to JDBC stored procedure in one line?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, execute

Hopefully someone can help. We're using a monitoring application, which connects to DBs via JDBC. In this particular case, we're connecting to a MSSQL DB using sqljdbc4.jar.

We need to execute a stored procedure and pass two parameters to it, but I'm struggling to figure out how exactly to do that. The software we use only allows one line to be passed to the JDBC query, if that makes sense.

I've tried the following:

```
{call procedure('my parameter 1','my parameter 2')}
```

That doesn't work though. From what I could google, typically I'd need to use this:

```
{call procedure-name(?,?)}
```

From there, parameter 1 and parameter 2 will need to be declared of sorts, with the prepared query then being passed to the DB. That is not an option in my case unfortunately.

Again turning to google, MS Technet specifies the following:

```
{[?=]call procedure-name[([parameter][,[parameter]]...)]}
```

I haven't tried this yet, but if I'm reading it correctly, could this potentially work?

```
{?='my parameter 1',?='my parameter 2' call procedure(?,?)}
```

I know I'm only supposed to ask after exhausting all my options, but I'm hoping someone out there has run into this before and managed to solve it. If anyone knows if the above will work, or of some other method that will do the trick, I'd appreciate your input dearly.

Comment: The format `{[?=]call procedure-name[([parameter][,[parameter]]...)]}` does not mean what you think it means. The `[?=]` means: optionally : `?=` for the return value. Note it is very important to update your question to include 1) at **minimum** the header of the stored procedure (but preferably the entire procedure), 2) the Java code you use to setup and execute this and 3) the exception message you receive.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, the software package we use does not allow Java code (unless kicking off a Java script perhaps). I also do not have the header or any access to the stored procedure other than the capability to run it with the DB user we've been assigned. I think to get around this, I'm going to go with what I know and write a Python script to carry this out. It's just weird to me that the parameters cannot be passed to the query directly when executing a stored procedure.